# Converting list of sequences into one-hot vectors

Tags: python, performance, matrix

I have an array of dim `1000 x 150` where I have 1000 strings each of length 150. And the strings only contain `ATCGN` (these are DNA sequences).

I am converting the letters to one-hot vectors such that `A` is `[1,0,0,0,0]` and  `N` is `[0,0,0,0,1]`.

I wrote the following code but it takes way too long when there are about 20 million strings.

```
def seqs2onehot(seqs, num_val):
    def one_hot_encode(seq):
        mapping = dict(zip("ACGTN", range(num_val)))
        seq = [mapping[i] for i in seq]
        return np.eye(num_val)[seq]
    onehotvecs = []
    for i in seqs:
        onehotvecs.append(np.array(one_hot_encode(i), dtype='bool'))
    return onehotvecs
```

To generate input:

```
num_inputs = 1000
inputs = []
for num in range(num_inputs):
    inputs.append(''.join(random.choice('ATCGN') for i in range(150)))
```

Outputs are of dimension `1000 x 150 x 5 x 1`.
You can create the final outputs by doing this:

```
inputs = np.array(inputs)
inputs = np.expand_dims(np.array(seqs2onehot(inputs, 5)), -1)
inputs.shape
```

Is there a way to do this without iterating through the list and just using matrix operations?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the expected formats for the input and output? I think that would help make this a bit clearer regarding your intentions. Otherwise, I'd say one of your main hangups is in using `append` 20 million times on a list. If you know your final size, pre-allocate your memory. Similarly, you do a lot of "regeneration on the fly" for things that could be defined statically and reused rather than created, used, and discarded, only to be re-created every single iteration.

Comment: @zephyr good idea, I've added in input output code.

Comment: What is the rationale for using “one hot vectors”? What is the rationale for encoding them in the way you have?

Comment: This is for a neural net that I'm training. But even otherwise, I come across similar coding problems and by learning through this example, I can extend it elsewhere...